# Can't get element using getElementByClass -Why Adobe Target cannot get the container value? Not loading the html content in the Adobe Target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, adobe

By add the following code in the console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container");
```

under the noraml web portal:
by adding the code in the console, I can get the container value.
The screenshot shows that there are **3 containers.**
[image]

Under Adobe Target, after loading the same website inside the Adobe Target, and adding the same code under console:
but the container is empty.

it shows that

```
HTMLCollection [  ]
```

it means that NO Container inside the Adobe Target.

[image]

How to solve this issue? How to fully load the html content in the Adobe Target? It was my first time encounting the issue. I am not sure why the html content not fully loaded in the Adobe Target. Hope you can help to solve the issue.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the elements with that class exist? Has Target amended the class names?

Comment: Adobe Target load the same website URL, the class should existed. I am not sure is something blocked by the Adobe Target. I check the html, all element is same as the web portal